# Magento 1.9.2.4 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' while saving categories

Tags: database, category-tree, save, magento1.9.2.4

I got the below error while saving some categories(not all categories)

```
2016-12-14T12:56:58+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint    violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array) 
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array) 
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array) 
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(78): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_url_info', Array) 
#8 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(94): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveUrlInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor)) 
#9 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(423): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor)) 
#10 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor)) 
#11 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() 
#12 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->saveByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) 
#13 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'saveByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) 
#14 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array) 
#15 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(551): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array) 
#16 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(75): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->postDispatch() 
#17 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(422): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->postDispatch() 
#18 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') 
#19 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#20 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#21 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#22 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/index.php(99): Mage::run('', 'store') 
#23 {main}
```

Anyone face this already.. If so please help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an issue in **magento log tables**.

***first Take backup of below tables***

```
log_customer
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_url
log_url_info
log_quote
```

*Then truncate the tables.*

This will resolved your  issue.

Comment: in cmdline fire `php -f magento_root/shell/log.php clean` command also work

Comment: i have tried this Amit..but still same issue.

Comment: May be you have  your log have issue

Comment: Do you know any other solutions?..

Comment: may be your log_customer
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_url
log_url_info
log_quote  corrupted.  You need to fix that.First rename those table and copy those table stucture from another default magento